# How to read a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, printing

I need to read a `csv` file (named `CityPop.csv`) and this is the code I have:

```
import csv

with open ('CityPop.csv', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
    for line in f:
        record=line.strip().split(",")
print read_data

f.close()
```

But when I try to run it, nothing is output.

I am not sure how to continue; this only leads into more advanced tasks I need to complete, which is difficult if I can't even figure this out.

Comment: `for line in read_data :`  use instead of `for line in f:`

Comment: Luckily there is the [csv modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: There are a number of separate issues with your code, but are you sure that `print read_data` prints nothing?

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey That would give a single character per iteration, not a line.

Comment: I think Python can not find your file. Try putting the whole path into the `open` statement.

Comment: please give `csv` format.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=python+read+csv+stackoverflow&cad=h

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
import csv

    with open ('CityPop.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        #read_data = f.read()
        for line in reader:
            print(line)
            #record=line.strip().split(",")
    #print (read_data)

    f.close()
```

EDIT 
As Ralf said 
"`f.close()` is not necessary when using a with block"

Comment: Improvement: `f.close()` is not necessary when using a `with` block

Answer (score 1):

**An easier way of reading csv files using pandas library -**

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('CityPop.csv')

print(df)
```

**or you can try modifying your code as below -**

```
import csv

with open ('CityPop.csv', 'r') as f:

  read_data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')

  for row in read_data:

            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module but never used it.
So try `read_data = csv.reader(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow the example from the docs of the python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import csv
with open('CityPop.csv') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=', ')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

---

Analizing your code, there are a few issues:

1. you don't need to call `f.close()` if you use a `with` statement, the file will be closed automatically when exiting the `with` block
2. your print statement should go inside the `with` block, as the variable `read_data` is defined inside it
3. you would need to iterate `read_data` (`for line in read_data:`), because you already used `f.read()` so that iterating over `f` will no yield anything
4. you are overwriting `record` each time, so I don't know why you want to it that way

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('CityPro.cvs') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in r:
            print(line)
    f.close()
```